# Find all a,b>0 so the series is convergent

Tags: real-analysis, sequences-and-series

I have following series
$$S=\sum_{n=1}^{\infty}\frac{n^{an+b}}{(an+b)^n}$$
Let $a\neq1$. I need to find all $a,b>0$ so the series is convergent.

I have tried a comparison test so
$$S\le\sum_{n=1}^{\infty}n^{an+b}=\sum_{n=1}^{\infty}\frac{1}{n^{-(an+b)}}$$
It looks like a p-series thats why
$-(an+b)>1$ in order for the series to be convergent.
The problem is i cant really conclude what a and b are. Any tips?
Thanks in advance

Answer (score 2):

We can apply ratio test here:
$$
\frac{a_{n+1}}{a_n} = \frac{(n+1)^{an + a + b}}{(an + a + b)^{n+1}} \cdot \frac{(an +b)^n}{n^{an + b}} = \left( 1+ \frac{1}{n} \right)^{an + b} \cdot \left(1 - \frac{a}{an + a + b} \right)^n \cdot \frac{(n + 1)^{a}}{an + a + b}.
$$
It's easy to see that
$$
\left( 1+ \frac{1}{n} \right)^{an + b} \to e^a,
$$
$$
\left(1 - \frac{a}{an + a + b} \right)^n \to \frac{1}{e},
$$
$$
\frac{(n + 1)^{a}}{an + a + b} \to \begin{cases} +\infty, & a > 1 \\ 0, & a < 1 \end{cases}
$$
So, series is divergent for $a > 1$ and convergent for $a < 1$.

Comment: And what can we say about b?

Comment: @SelbyChing convergence doesn't depend on $b$

Comment: And what if a=1?

Comment: $a \neq 1$ in your question.

Comment: I meant it as an additional question.

Answer (score 1):

We have that

- for $a\ge 1$ eventually $n^a\ge an$ and then

$$x_n=\frac{n^{an+b}}{(an+b)^n}=\left(\frac {n^a}{an}\right)^n\frac{n^{b}}{\left(1+\frac b{an}\right)^n} \to \infty$$

and S diverges, while

- for $0<a<1$ by limit comparison test with $\frac1{n^{n\frac{1-a}2}}$ we have

$$\frac{x_n}{\frac1{n^{n\frac{1-a}2}}}=\left(\frac {1}{an^{\frac{1-a}2}}\right)^n\frac{n^{b}}{\left(1+\frac b{an}\right)^n}\to 0$$

and S converges.

Comment: How would you tackle it if a=1 and u have to find all b>0 so the series is convergent

Comment: For $a=1$ $$x_n=\frac{n^{an+b}}{(an+b)^n}=\left(\frac {n}{n}\right)^n\frac{n^{b}}{\left(1+\frac b{an}\right)^n}=\frac{n^{b}}{\left(1+\frac b{an}\right)^n} \to \infty$$ for any $b>0$. For convergence with $a=1$, we need $b<-1$.